# Possible to determine size of file to be downloaded?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I currently have the following code which reads a file located on the web and writes it to a file on the phone:

```
InputStream inputStream = new URL(sourceFileWebAddress).openStream();
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);

int count;
byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];

while ((count = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)
  fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
```

Does anyone know whether it is possible (using the setup above or otherwise) to determine the total number of bytes which are to be read before commencing with the download (in order to publish percentage progress to the user as the download proceeds)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use the `getContentLength` method of `URLConnection`

```
URL url = new URL(sourceFileWebAddress);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();

int fileLenth = connection.getContentLength();

InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
```

Comment: Also the content length may be -1 if the server does not support this or for some reason the file size is unknown.

Comment: WARNING: `url.openConnection().getContentLength()` will do a `GET` and not a `HEAD`. See answer from Santosh below for a better method (i.e., do `connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD")` before calling `getContentLength()`).

Answer (score 3):

try this out using **[URLConnnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html)**

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(sourceFileWebAddress).openConnection();
InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

System.out.println("total size: "+connection.getContentLength();//size

BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);

int count;
byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];

while ((count = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)
  fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
```

Answer (score 3):

TO determine the total number of bytes which are to be read **before** commencing with the download, one way is to *only get the response headers* by sending a **HTTP HEAD** request as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

public class SimpleHTTPRequest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      HttpURLConnection connection = null;
      URL serverAddress = null;

      try {
          String sourceFileWebAddress = "http://localhost:8080/mycontents";
          serverAddress = new URL(sourceFileWebAddress);
          //set up out communications stuff
          connection = null;

          //Set up the initial connection
          connection = (HttpURLConnection)serverAddress.openConnection();

          //HEAD request will make sure that the contents are not downloaded.
          connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");  

          connection.connect();
          System.out.println("========"+connection.getContentLength());

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ProtocolException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally
      {
          //close the connection, set all objects to null
          connection.disconnect();

          connection = null;
      }
  }
}
```

This will print the size of the content to be downloaded **without actually downloading** the contents.

Comment: The documentation of the `URLConnection.getContentLength()` method (as suggested by the other answerers) reads: "Returns the content length in bytes specified by the response header field `content-length` or -1 if this field is not set." So it seems this method is in fact also not downloading the contents. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Adil, Yes, That's right. It receives only headers without triggering the file download.

Comment: No, `url.openConnection().getContentLength()` will do a `GET` (in at least Java 7). Setup a server side and check out the requests a Java client sends over.

Comment: @GregSmethells, if the method was GET, it would have returned the content as well which it does not.

Comment: @Santosh sounds like you never inspected the server-side. It does a GET by default and simply close its end of the socket mid-stream (causes a broken pipe on the server-side which is how we found it).

Answer (score 2):

You can send a request to the server to return the filesize. Use that filesize in your progressbar and initiate the download.So these are two separate requests but you can bundle them in the same asyc task. 
So you first get the fielszie, make a call to `progressUpdate` where you set the values for progressbar and then continue with the download with periodic calls to `progressUpdate()` to change the status of progressbar.

Answer (score 1):

The method `getContentLength` of `URLConnection` should give you the size of the file to be downloaded. From this you can draw your ProgressBar as you like, updating it (in onProgressUpdate, assuming you're doing this inside an AsyncTask. you are, right?) whenever new data is processed by your fileOutputStream.

If the server doesn't give you a value in getContentLength (-1 in most cases, but at least check if it's less than or equal to zero), just make your ProgressBar indeterminate.