# Primefaces progress bar live update

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am currently trying to incorporate a progress bar into my application to display the current progress of a task. The task, retrieves a file from a server using a web service. i do not have access to this web service and therefore cannot put any code inside it.

My code is as follows:

The method which I need to display progress of:

```
    public URL checkout(String docCid, String fileCid)
{
    String userId="aaaaaa";


    FVConnectData fvData = new FVConnectData();
    fvData.setWsKeyword("aaaaa");
    fvData.setWsUrl("http://aaaaa.com");
    FVConnector con = new FVConnector(fvData);
    System.out.println("Method checkout called");

    URL url = null;
    try
    {
       //This is where the web service is called
       url = con.checkoutFile(docCid, fileCid, userId, "aaaa", "aaaa", false);
       System.out.println("URL: " + url.toString());


       return url;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

       System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
       e.printStackTrace();

       return null;
    }

}
```

My question is this:

How can I adapt this method in order to provide my primefaces GUI with the live progress of the method to display to the user?

EDIT:

The only real examples I have found online use a random progress to display on the progress bar. I do not want this, I want the true (or close enough) progress. Also due to not being able to access the web service, I am unable to determine the size of the file before hand.

Comment: Why not use `AjaxStatus`. It's my suggestion, i think it can be more simple. Until the `checkout` as not finished, you show `AjaxStatus`, after method finish is task, you can show an message (error or success).

Comment: Do you mean instead of a progress bar? or alongside a progress bar?

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand `AjaxStatus`. From what I can gather, it has two attributes - start and complete. Therefore, I can set a message to say when the process has started and one to say when the process has finished (whether successful or erroneous) and nothing in between. Is this correct?

Comment: @ColdHack If this is so, it is not really what I am looking for, because as an interim until im able to solve my problem, I use a BlockUI displaying a loading gif while the process takes place. However, due to the hugely varying times of the process depending on the file size, it can take a very long time to complete the process and is not clear whether the process is being performed or if it has stalled. Therefore I was looking for a way to constantly track the process as much as possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm assuming taht you call this method on a `p:commandButton` right? If it's right, you need only to add the ajax status component, and next, on `onStart` attribute you call an `p:dialog` with an gif image (can be a progress bar gif). On `oncomplete` you just hide the dialog.

Comment: It is called on selection from selectOneMenu but that would only display the same as i currently have effectively wouldnt it?

Comment: While dialog is visible, we can assume that the process is elapsing

Comment: Hum, ok. In this cas i have no ideia how to get the actual state of process.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914494/possible-to-determine-size-of-file-to-be-downloaded) link can help you to work around.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. Thanks for the link @danRod, however due to the way the web service is setup, that approach is not viable.